# How to Assign Custom Data Source Names in Looker Studio Community Connector

Tags: looker-studio

I'm currently working on developing a Looker Studio Community Connector to enable users to access their data stored in our database. With this connector, users can access a diverse range of data, and their choices in configuring data sources play a key role in this process.

My goal is to utilise the config parameters selected by users to provide more user-friendly and intuitive names for the data sources.

For reference, the Google Sheets plugin automatically names the data source after the selected sheet, and I'm aiming to achieve a similar functionality within the community connector.

I tried searching the community connector documentation but could not find a way to achieve this.